# CakePHP not binding model automatically

Tags: php, cakephp

CakePHP 2.8.3 is not binding the model automatically.

Model :

```
<?php
class Item extends AppModel
{

    public $name = 'Item';

    public $belongsTo = array(

        'Cat' => array(
            'className'  => 'Cat',
            'foreignKey' => 'cat_id',
        ),

    );

}
```

The above Model is not working.

However when I Bind Model in controller. It works fine.

```
$this->Item->bindModel(array(
            'belongsTo' => array(
            'Cat' => array(
            'foreignKey' => 'cat_id',
            ))));
```

What could be the cause ?

Comment: check the filename is should be same as controller name like if controller name is ItemController then the modal should be as ItemModal in modal folder

Comment: There was file name error. I named it as ItemModal.php intead of Item.php